# query a class object using linq

Tags: linq, class, object, lambda

I am trying to query a class object.

My class :

```
public class Result
{
   public List<Driver>  Drivers { get; set; }
   public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }       
}
```

I have method to which I am passing an object of this class

```
  public string BuildRequestXML(Result  input)
     { 
       var driverNames = new List<Name>(); 
       input.Drivers.ForEach(cd => driverNames.Add(cd.Name)); 
     }
```

I get Object reference not set to instance error @ the 2nd line of code in the above function.
Thanks in advance.
BB.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Examine exception stack trace? Breakpoints in VS? With such a description it seems like an easiest error to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to debug to find which one it is, but that exception could be because either `input` or `input.Drivers` is null. You could even have a null `Driver` in the `Drivers` list.

As for your `driversName` list, you could rewrite that as

```
var driverNames = input.Drivers.Select(driver => driver.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I see my Drivers list count = 1. Still I recieve this error. Please see the screenshot attached to the original question.

Comment: @BumbleBee - You're getting good advice from @ColinE and @Anthony. Try rewriting it without LINQ (use a foreach loop) and debug it. You'll find your bug.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure why you are getting this problem, however, a better approach would be to use a Select 'projection' as follows:

```
driverNames  = input.Drivers.Select(d => d.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Colin Thank you.  input and Drivers are not null. Still I get same error.